# Is there a penalty for having multiple small Firebase functions for same subscription?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a React web app that uses Firestore as its database and multiple (10+) Firebase functions per Firestore collection for side effects such as posting to social media, etc:

```
exports.onUserSignUp = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
  // Insert into users collection
  // Insert into profiles collection
  // Notify via Discord webhook
  // insert into history collection to keep track of actions performed by users
})

exports.onCityCreate = functions.firestore.document('cities/{cityId}').onCreate(doc => {
  // Notify via Discord webhook
  // Send tweet
  // Update cache in a collection
  // Insert into history collection to keep track of actions performed by users
})
```

etc.

In the Firebase functions tutorials they often recommend you declare a Firebase function for a side-effect like this:

```
exports.onCityCreate = functions.firestore.document('/cities/{documentId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    ...
  })
```

This makes sense if you have a single small side effect - eg. send a tweet via Twitter REST API - but over time I have added more and more side effects such as sending to Discord via webhook, inserting new records into other databases, caching data and more.

When I learned about lambdas in AWS I was taught to make my functions small and limited to one job instead of 1 large function. This means if 1 side effect fails it wont bring down the other side-effects. It makes the code easier to understand and read. It makes it easier to debug.

So the funcs above could be split up to each job:

```
exports.sendTweetOnCityCreate =  functions.firestore.document('cities/{cityId}').onCreate(doc => {
  // send tweet via REST API
})

exports.sendDiscordOnCityCreate =  functions.firestore.document('cities/{cityId}').onCreate(doc => {
  // send Discord message via webhook
})

exports.updateCitiesCache =  functions.firestore.document('cities/{cityId}').onCreate(doc => {
  // update a record in a cache collection with some kind of tally etc.
})

exports.recordCityInHistory =  functions.firestore.document('cities/{cityId}').onCreate(doc => {
  // insert into history collection to keep track of actions performed by users
})
```

**Is there a penalty (performance - slower or financial - more cost from Google) for declaring a small, independent function for each side effect instead of 1 large function that "does all" like I currently have?**

Answer (score 1):

There will be no discernible change in performance.  The time it takes for an event to get delivered from Firestore to the function is going to be essentially the same no matter how many functions you have.

The worst thing that will happen with an all-in-one approach is that your function doesn't scale massively, as each function is capped to 1000 concurrent server instances handling its events.  But that's quite a lot of instances.  If you split your functions up, they will each be able to scale up to 1000 server instances each.  This would only be useful at very large scales though.

Comment: Can you add some reference for your thought?